# Can't get a VLookup to reference another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

So I'm relatively new to VBA and I'm trying to get a Vlookup to return a value searching on another workbook. The thing is, i keep getting the classic

> 1004 error

on the line of the Vlookup. I'm just trying to search for a number on the current workbook and find it on another one, returning the date associated to it, but it doesn't give me anything

I've seen many people asking stuff like this, but haven't seen the answer to my specififc problema, which I guess is common among beginners. So, any help on how to make a better code, besides the actual solution to my problema is appreciated.

```
Sub Add_Dates()

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Dim Lastzip As Integer, Val As Integer

    'Open this workbook just in case it's not yet selected
    Workbooks.Open ("C:\(%)\combine zslb and zpdi.xlsm")
    LastRow = Range("A1").End(x1Down).Row 
    'get the value for the last row

    Workbooks.Open ("C:\(%)\zipe zpdi zslb.xlsx")
    Sheets("ZSLB").Activate
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(x1LastCell).Select
    Lastzip = ActiveCell.Row
    'Same, get the value of the last row of this wbk, 
    'which changes everyday, so can't be a fix value

    Workbooks("combine zslb and zpdi.xlsm").Sheets("zslb").Activate
    Range("A2").End(x1ToRight).Select
    col = Selection.Offset(0,1).Column

    For i = 2 to LastRow
        Val = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, 1), Workbooks("zipe zpdi zslb.xlsx"). _
            Sheets("ZSLB").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Lastzip, 31)), 31, False)
        Cells(i, col).Value = Val
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What does `, 31, False` in the `.Range` means?

Comment: It's outside the `.Range` part, the final two arguments for the `Vlookup`

Comment: `Workbooks("combine zslb and zpdi.xlsm.xlsm")` You have `.xlsm` written twice on here, will this cause an issue too? Also, on what line is there error occuring?

Comment: Oops, sorry about that, it's well written on the actual code, so that wasn't a problem. The error is on the `val=apllication.vlookup`... line

Comment: Your unqualified Cells() calls will point to the activesheet, whatever that happens to be: if that's the wrong sheet you'll get an error.  Also, you should `Dim Val as Variant` to allow for the case where VLookup returns an error because there was no match.

Comment: Okay, and could you tell me how can I make them point to the other workbook? That's precisely the part I'm struggling with. Thanks.

Comment: You will find accessing worksheets much easier if you Dim references to each worksheet/workbook you're going to use. Also you could consider using Index/Match or Find/Offset functions rather than VLookups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but compiled:

```
Sub Add_Dates()

    Const WB_PATH As String = "C:\(%)\"

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Dim LastZipRow As Long, LastCombRow As Long, col As Long, v
    Dim wbComb As Workbook, wbZipe As Workbook, i As Long
    Dim shtComb As Workbook, shtZipe As Workbook, rngLookup As Range

    Set wbComb = GetWorkbook(WB_PATH, "combine zslb and zpdi.xlsm")
    Set wbZipe = GetWorkbook(WB_PATH, "zipe zpdi zslb.xlsx")

    Set shtComb = wbComb.Sheets("ZSLB")
    Set shtZipe = wbZipe.Sheets("ZSLB")

    LastCombRow = shtComb.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    LastZipRow = shtZipe.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    col = shtComb.Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column

    Set rngLookup = shtZipe.Range(shtZipe.Cells(2, 1), _
                                  shtZipe.Cells(LastZipRow, 31))

    For i = 2 To LastCombRow
        v = Application.VLookup(shtComb.Cells(i, 1), rngLookup, 31, False)
        shtComb.Cells(i, col).Value = IIf(IsError(v), "???", v)
    Next i

End Sub

'return a reference to an already-open file, or if not open then open it
Function GetWorkbook(wbPath, wbName) As Workbook
    Dim rv As Workbook
    If Right(wbPath, 1) <> "\" Then wbPath = wbPath & "\"
    On Error Resume Next '<< ignore error if file not open
    Set rv = Workbooks(wbName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    'note there's no error handling here to account for "file not found"
    If rv Is Nothing Then Set rv = Workbooks.Open(wbPath & wbName)
    Set GetWorkbook = rv
End Function
```

Note - in your constants you're using a "1" and not "l" - e.g. `x1Down`.

Comment: After a few tweaks, it Works! Thank you very much! 
However, I do have a small question, it only works if the other Workbook is not open. How can I modify it so it works regardless of the "openness" of the other book?
Thank you anyways!